# Display MultiLine in Different X position using FPDF MultiCell Function

Tags: php, fpdf

Hi everybody,
               i am struggle with MultiCell function. what i am trying to say is i want to print 3 or 4 line content.so i used MultiCell like this
 `$pdf->SetXY(34,139);
    $pdf->MultiCell(145,6,strtoupper($data));`
so this line print the data at `X=34` but the next line also start at 34 here i need the second line must start at 10 . how to do that. give a solution to this.

i already tried this -> store the value returned by substring of the data for width 65(`$cont=substring($data,0,65);`) and remaining in another variable but it divide the string  meaningless.

Thanks & Regards,
riash

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use a multi-cell, just using

```
$pdf->Write()
```

will display line breaks and will revert to the left margin after each break

```
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', '10');
$pdf->SetXY(20, 10);
$pdf->Write(5, "First line\r\nSecond line");
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/pdf.pdf', 'F');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This makes the assumption the OP (and others) have enough insight into the value of `$data` that they can intelligently place `\r\n`. I came here with the same question, and I have nowhere near that level of control over it. I could simply break it apart before using FPDF, but that's the point of using MultiCell, isn't it?